# Como mostrar texto en Select list de Form EN django tipo 'placeholder'

Tags: django, django-forms

Quisiera agregar un texto por defecto al select list así como el 'placeholder' de un TextInput, pero no lo consigo, aqui en el form tengo el widgets:

'especialidad' :  forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'seleccione su especialidad'}),

claro esto no funciona por que no es la forma correcta, entonces como debería hacerlo, es posible? 
de ante mano, gracias, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, es muy fácil conseguir lo que deseas, lo único es que no hace parte de ningún widget si no un atributo especial del modelo ModelChoiceField, que es un Field (`django.forms.fields.Field`), entonces, debes saber como setearlo adecuadamente. Al ser un atributo especial de ModelChoiceField, quiere decir que solo funcionará en campos que sean relaciones con otros modelos, de esta forma:

```
class Formulario(forms.ModelForm):
    empty_label_message = 'Este seria mi placeholder para un select'

    relation_2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(
       queryset=MyOtherModel.objects.all(), empty_label=empty_label_message)

    class Meta:
       model = MyModel
       fields = ('name', 'relation_1', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['relation_1'].empty_label = empty_label_message
```

Esas serian dos de las formas posibles de agregar tu 'Placeholder' a un select en django.

Cualquier duda, comenta.

Comment: gracias por responder! lo comprendo como lo plantea, ahora bien como pasarle esa informacion al select? es decir en mi:  forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), ?, gracias!

Comment: Te vuelvo a repetir que de esta forma solo puedes hacerlo con un CAMPO y no con un WIDGET, donde `forms.Select` es un WIDGET, si quieres hacerlo en tu WIDGET, añade un arreglo de opciones (choices), y pon luego por defecto la opcion que quieres que salga como placeholder, tendrías que agregar el atributo choices, y el atributo default o initial